# Spring Security 4 intercept anonymous user AccessDeniedException

Tags: spring-security

My website allows unauthenticated (anonymous) users to perform a search of content which requires authentication to view. Currently, when they click on a link to view the details of one of the content items on the search results page Spring Security correctly identifies the user as unauthenticated and displays the login page. However, I would like to intervene and instead display a page to encourage the anonymous user to sign up for the website.  I have traced what is happening in the filter chain but it's not clear to me whether I should extend an existing filter or handler or create a custom filter or handler. If it's the later I'm not sure where it should go.

When I run this through debug I can see the following happening:

- `ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter` executes `FilterSecurityInterceptor` which determines that the detail page requires authentication (returns a -1 vote and throws an `AccessDeniedException`)
- `ExceptionTranslationFilter` catches the exception, determines the user is anonymous and calls the `authenticationEntryPoint`, in this case `LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint`
- `LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint` invokes the `DefaultRedirectStrategy` which redirects to the login page

So, basically I need to override the redirection to the login page for this one use case. My best guess is to create a custom filter that checks for the combination of an anonymous user accessing this specific detail page and forces a redirect to the join up page, inserting the filter in the chain after `ExceptionTranslationFilter`. Or is this total overkill for handling a single page redirect and there's an easier way to accomplish this?

Comment: No, create and inject a custom `AuthenticationEntryPoint` one which decided to which page to redirect instead of the default login page. Don't hack the filter just create a proper entry point.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for the tip - it worked perfectly!  The only side effect is members of the site will see the join up page if they haven't logged in yet, but that is actually ok since the verbiage on the page covers that situation.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested, here's the code for the custom auth entry point, borrowing from `LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint` and `ExceptionTranslationFilter`.

```
public class CustomAuthLoginEntryPoint extends LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    private PortResolver portResolver = new PortResolverImpl();
    private AuthenticationTrustResolver trustResolver = new AuthenticationTrustResolverImpl();
    private RequestCache requestCache = new HttpSessionRequestCache();
    private final RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();
    private String joinPageUrl;

    public CustomAuthLoginEntryPoint(String loginFormUrl) {
        super(loginFormUrl);
    }

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        logger.debug("commence");

        String redirectUrl = null;

        if (!StringUtils.isBlank(joinPageUrl)) {
            Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
            if (auth == null || trustResolver.isAnonymous(auth)) {
                SavedRequest savedRequest = requestCache.getRequest(request, response);
                redirectUrl = savedRequest.getRedirectUrl();

                if (redirectUrl.indexOf("viewDetail") > 0) {
                    String joinPageUrl = buildRedirectUrlToJoinPage(request);
                    logger.debug("Redirecting to '" + joinPageUrl + "'");
                    redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, joinPageUrl);
                    return;
                }               
            }
        }

        super.commence(request, response, authException);
    }

    protected String buildRedirectUrlToJoinPage(HttpServletRequest request) {

        int serverPort = portResolver.getServerPort(request);
        String scheme = request.getScheme();

        RedirectUrlBuilder urlBuilder = new RedirectUrlBuilder();

        urlBuilder.setScheme(scheme);
        urlBuilder.setServerName(request.getServerName());
        urlBuilder.setPort(serverPort);
        urlBuilder.setContextPath(request.getContextPath());
        urlBuilder.setPathInfo(joinPageUrl);

        return urlBuilder.getUrl();
    }

    public void setJoinPage(String joinPageUrl) {
        this.joinPageUrl = joinPageUrl;
    }
}
```

I added this to my `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`:

```
@Bean
public CustomAuthLoginEntryPoint customAuthLoginEntryPoint() {
    CustomAuthLoginEntryPoint entryPoint = new CustomAuthLoginEntryPoint("/user/login");
    entryPoint.setJoinPage("/user/join");
    return entryPoint;
}
```

and the http configure:

```
    .exceptionHandling()
        .accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler())
        .authenticationEntryPoint(customAuthLoginEntryPoint())
```